# Deezer API: check if the current user has the 30-seconds streaming limit

Tags: javascript, api, deezer

is there a way, for a web application, to check if the current user has the 30-seconds streaming limit or not?

It can happen in two cases:

- the user is not logged
- the user is logged but his account doesn't allow the full streaming from an external web application (I guess this second case can be just a free user over his first 6 months subscription period).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an hack for this:

```
DZ.Event.subscribe('player_position', function(arg){
if (arg[1] == 30 ){
alert('limit 30 secs');
});
```

pay attention because at the beginning of the song, for some reason, arg[1] is 0